# How to find the default tab index of controls?

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to find the default tab index of the form.

I have not given but still all the control has the tab index. I want to find that default tab index through the j query. How can i find that?

Answer (score 0):

## Jquery and tab-index

The way tabindexing works is that it goes trough your html markup and looks for tabable elements.

So say you have this code:

```html
<form>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The text input will be tabbed first, and then the submit input.
Yes i know this how do it get the tabbing?

```js
$(function() {
  $firstinput = $("form").find("input")
  console.log($firstinput.first()); //prints the first element thats an input.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The code above will only work if you only have input elemtns and add not trickery to the markup like hiding your elements etc.

In the code below im using the jquery UI `:focusable` selector.
With this you should get the first tabbable element in your form

```js
//:focus selector from jquery UI
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  focusable: function(element) {
    var nodeName = element.nodeName.toLowerCase(),
      tabIndex = $.attr(element, 'tabindex');
    return (/input|select|textarea|button|object/.test(nodeName) ? !element.disabled : 'a' == nodeName || 'area' == nodeName ? element.href || !isNaN(tabIndex) : !isNaN(tabIndex))
      // the element and all of its ancestors must be visible
      // the browser may report that the area is hidden
      && !$(element)['area' == nodeName ? 'parents' : 'closest'](':hidden').length;
  }
});

//actual code
$(function() {
  $form = $("form");
  $first = $form.find(":focusable").first();
  console.log($first);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label tab-index="0">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for 'tabindex' attribute with jquery.

`var tabindexVal = $('selector').attr('tabindex');`

Comment: I want to find the default tab index which applies when i am not giving any tab index.

Comment: i think tabindex zero means using appear order for tabindex. So you can test for jquery select order for inputs like that `$('input').each(function(index){ console.log(index); });`